# Using C++ regex for multi match

Tags: c++, regex

I want to parse relatively simple registry file format, let's assume it's plain ascii, saved in old REGEDIT4 format. I want to parse it using standard c++ regex class or function (preferably no boost). As an input data it could take for example sample file like this:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\ConfigurationData\v1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\ConfigurationData\v1.0\General]
"SettingDword"=dword:00000009
"Setting1"="Some string 1"
"SettingString2"="my String"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\ConfigurationData\v1.0\Networking]
"SettingDword2"=dword:00000002
"Setting2"="Some string 2"
"SettingString3"="my String2"
```

What I have briefly analyzed - scanning multiple [] can be done using for example `cregex_token_iterator` class, but main problem is that it is working in opposite way, which I want to use it. I want to start matching pattern like this: `regex re("(\\[.*?\\])")`, but token iterator returns all strings, which were not matched, which does sounds kind silly to me.

Basically I would like to match first whole section `(\\[.*?\\])(.*?\n\n)`, and then pick up registry path first, and key-values next - then split using regex key-value pairs.

It's really incredible that in C# it's relatively easy to write regex matcher like this, but I would prefer go with C++, as it's native, does not have performance and assembly unload problems.

Answer (score 0):

Finally cross analyzed - it's possible to use `regex_search`, but search needs to be retried by continuing from next char* after found pattern.

Below is almost complete example to load .reg file at run-time, I'm using MFC's `CString`, because it's slightly easier to use than `std::string` and portability is not needed currently.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <afx.h>                //CFile
#include "TestRegex.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <map>

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;
typedef enum
{
    eREG_DWORD = REG_DWORD,
    eREG_QWORD = REG_QWORD,
    eREG_BINARY = REG_BINARY,
    eREG_SZ = REG_SZ
}eRegType;

class RegVariant
{
public:
    eRegType type;

    union
    {
        DWORD dw;
        __int64 qw;
    };

    CStringA str;
};



class RegKeyNode
{
public:
    // Paths to next nodes
    map<CStringA, RegKeyNode> keyToNode;

    // Values of current key
    map<CStringA, RegVariant> keyValues;
};

map<HKEY, RegKeyNode> g_registry;

int char2int(char input)
{
    if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        return input - '0';
    if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'F')
        return input - 'A' + 10;
    if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'f')
        return input - 'a' + 10;
    return 0;
}

void hexToBin( const char* hex, CStringA& bin, int maxSize = -1 )
{
    int size = (strlen(hex) + 1)/ 3;

    if(maxSize != -1 && size > maxSize)
        size = maxSize;

    unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*)bin.GetBuffer(size);
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        buf[i] = char2int( hex[ i*3 ] ) * 16 + char2int(hex[i * 3 + 1]);

    bin.ReleaseBuffer();
}


int main()
{
    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    AfxWinInit(hModule, nullptr, ::GetCommandLine(), 0);


    //
    //  Load .reg file.
    //
    CString fileName = L"test1.reg";
    CStringA file;
    CFile cfile;

    if (cfile.Open(fileName, CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareDenyNone))
    {
        int len = (int)cfile.GetLength();
        cfile.Read(file.GetBuffer(len), len);
        file.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
    cfile.Close();
    file.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

    const char* pbuf = file.GetBuffer();
    regex reSection("\\[(.*?)\\]([^]*?)\n\n");
    regex reLine("^\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*=\\s*(.*)$");
    regex reTypedValue("^(hex|dword|hex\\(b\\)):(.*)$");
    regex reStringValue("^\"(.*)\"$" );
    cmatch cmSection, cmLine;

    //
    //  For each section:
    //
    //  [registry path]
    //  "value1"="value 1"
    //  "value2"="value 1"
    //
    while( regex_search(pbuf, pbuf + strlen(pbuf), cmSection, reSection) )
    {
        CStringA path = cmSection[1].str().c_str();
        string key_values = cmSection[2].str();
        const char* pkv = key_values.c_str();

        int iPath = 0;
        CStringA hkeyName = path.Tokenize("\\", iPath).MakeUpper();

        RegKeyNode* rnode;
        if( hkeyName.Compare("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE") == 0 )
            rnode = &g_registry[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE];
        else
            rnode = &g_registry[HKEY_CURRENT_USER];     // Don't support other HKEY roots.

        //
        //  Locate path where to place values.
        //
        for( ; hkeyName = path.Tokenize("\\", iPath); )
        {
            if( hkeyName.IsEmpty() )
                break;

            rnode = &rnode->keyToNode[hkeyName];
        }

        //
        //  Scan "key"="value" pairs.
        //
        while( regex_search(pkv, pkv+strlen(pkv), cmLine, reLine ))
        {
            CStringA key = cmLine[1].str().c_str();
            string valueType = cmLine[2].str();
            smatch cmTypeValue;
            RegVariant* rvValue = &rnode->keyValues[key];

            //
            //  Extract type and value.
            //
            if(regex_search(valueType, cmTypeValue, reTypedValue))
            {
                string type = cmTypeValue[1].str();
                string value = cmTypeValue[2].str();

                if( type == "dword")
                {
                    rvValue->type = eREG_DWORD;
                    rvValue->dw = (DWORD)strtoul(value.c_str(), 0, 16);
                }
                else if (type == "hex(b)")
                {
                    rvValue->type = eREG_QWORD;
                    rvValue->qw = 0;
                    if( value.size() == 8 * 2 + 7 )
                    {
                        CStringA v;
                        hexToBin(value.c_str(), v, sizeof(__int64));
                        rvValue->qw = *((__int64*)v.GetBuffer());
                    }
                } else //if (type == "hex")
                {
                    rvValue->type = eREG_BINARY;
                    hexToBin(value.c_str(), rvValue->str);
                }

            } else if( regex_search(valueType, cmTypeValue, reStringValue))
            {
                rvValue->type = eREG_SZ;
                rvValue->str = cmTypeValue[1].str().c_str();
            }

            pkv = cmLine[2].second;
        } //while

        pbuf = cmSection[2].second;
    } //while


    return 0;
}
```